# Is it ok to cut an access panel into the drywall above my service panel?

Tags: drywall

I recently purchased this house so have inherited what is here.

My main panel is located in the attached garage. It is built into a semi-finished wall.
The previous owner cut a small "door/window" ( *see photo* ) in the drywall above the main panel - presumably to make fishing wires easier.

The "door" of drywall is only removable when removing the cover of the panel.

There is a similar situation below the main panel - with a section of what i think is MDF that is not attached.  The way the MDF is situated I could not remove it without breaking it, but I can flex the top of it to see behind it.

I am updating some of my circuits so will need to have an inspection in the near future.

I'm curious if any of this is cause for concern?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code requires the wires to be covered it doesn’t specify anything other than 1/2” Sheetrock or plywood. I do create access points in my home and some jobs that need them the only difference is I have a piece of trim over the cut usually held in place by Velcro. I can see an inspector having an issue with the cut especially if the wall is common with a living space , if an outside wall I doubt they would say anything.

Added for more info:
Note sometimes these flaps are cut so the clamps can be installed. I use a plastic clamp called “insiders” Raco brand, punch the knockout feed the wire through the hole then slide the insider down the wire into the hole and it clamps the wire. I used to have to cut those flaps but with the insiders I just have to fish the wire through the hole. 
Note I have no links to these other than I love them and have been using them for quite a while saving time and $ even on new installs.